# bubbling up errors in service objects to controllers

Tags: error-handling, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a service object that calls to an external service(Service::Customer) like following

```
class CustomerService
  def initialise(params)
    @email = params[:email]
  end

  def save_customer
    Service::Customer.create(@email)
  end
end
```

my controller contains a create method

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    new_customer = CustomerService.new({email: params[:email]})
    new_customer.save_customer
  rescue Service::CustomerCreationError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to new_customer_path
  end
end
```

my question is what is the best way I can move the error handling to the service object ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to raise the same type of error caught in the service file, and then rescue that error in the controller.

**Service**

```
    def service_method 
      do stuff...
    rescue ActiveRecord::UnknownAttribute => e
      raise ActiveRecord::UnknownAttribute.new "An error occurred in the 
 service method: #{e}"
    rescue StandardError => e
      raise StandardError.new "An unknown error occurred in the service method: #{e}"
    end
```

**Controller**

```
def controller_method
  do stuff...
rescue ActiveRecord::UnknownAttribute => e
  Rails.logger.error "An error occurred: #{e}
rescue StandardError => e
  Rails.logger.error "Error occurred: #{e}
end
```

So basically catch, re-raise, catch, re-raise until you get to where you want to use the error for something.